# Clean way to default child record values from parent record in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, action, childrecords

A customer is asking that a status field on a child record be defaulted to a value from a parent record when the "New" button is used on the "Related" tab of the parent record.

Can this be accomplished in Lightning Experience just using the default layouts?

(In Classic, the request can be routed through a page/controller to add parameters to the URL; that is a hack.)

Comment: is custom quick action good enough?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I thought that only allowed constants not references to values from the parent?

Comment: I created a quick Action on Account to create an Opportunity and on Predefined Field Values I was able to refer and use Account fields( Account.AccountNumber ) .

Comment: @PranayJaiswal My bad - excellent! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Action on Parent to create child records would work a charm. Also, we can prepopulate child record's fields from parent using `Predefined Field Values` which is somewhat similar to classic(pre-populating fields url hack)

[image]

A tip from Salesforce docs says:

> On object-specific actions, the predefined value can include
>   references to the source object and its related objects

Src: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5